# How to get the legend of a Vector heatmap layer in QGIS 2.14.4?

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, style, legend, heat-map

I'm new on QGIS and PyQGIS. I'm trying to create a plugin which aims to apply a style on a vector layer (generated from a csv file) and then save the map as a png file.

The style I apply on the vector layer is a heatmap style. The problem is that I don't have a legend for the heatmap.. .
At least I would like to have the colors and the percentage of the different levels.

Do you have any idea of how I could do that? Or is it even possible?

I'm not using the heatmap plugin, only applying a heatmap style from a .qml file.

I searched a lot and I couldn't find anything helpful about that... any help would be great.

Answer (score 3):

You may get access to the default ramp colors in this way:

```
defStyle = QgsStyleV2().defaultStyle()
defaultColorRampNames = defStyle.colorRampNames()
print defaultColorRampNames

# The print command returns this list:
# [u'Blues', u'BrBG', u'BuGn', u'BuPu', u'GnBu', u'Greens', u'Greys', u'Inferno', u'Magma', u'OrRd', u'Oranges', u'PRGn', u'PiYG', u'Plasma', u'PuBu', u'PuBuGn', u'PuOr', u'PuRd', u'Purples', u'RdBu', u'RdGy', u'RdPu', u'RdYlBu', u'RdYlGn', u'Reds', u'Spectral', u'Viridis', u'YlGn', u'YlGnBu', u'YlOrBr', u'YlOrRd']
```

Then, you may set the ramp by specifying the index of the ramp from the list printed in the previous code (for example, `0` is the index for the 'Blues' ramp):

```
ramp = defStyle.colorRamp(defaultColorRampNames[0]) # 0 is the index for the 'Blues' ramp
```

or by directly typing the color ramp's name:

```
ramp = defStyle.colorRamp('Blues')
```

With these premises, you may use this sample code:

```
layer = iface.activeLayer() # load the layer as you want

defStyle = QgsStyleV2().defaultStyle()
defaultColorRampNames = defStyle.colorRampNames()

renderer = QgsHeatmapRenderer()
renderer.setRadius(5) # change the radius value as you want
renderer.setMaximumValue(0) # set 0 for automatically calculating it
ramp = defStyle.colorRamp('Blues')
renderer.setColorRamp(ramp)
renderer.setWeightExpression('my_field') # set the field name here
layer.setRendererV2(renderer)
layer.triggerRepaint()
```

for creating a **Heatmap renderer** (of *blues*):

[image]